# lxml duplicate child elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

How to add element with check in lxml.
I am creating an xml using lxml(4.1.1) in python(2.7).

The problem I am facing is duplicate elements getting added in xml.
For example -

```
  <parent>
    <child>text1</child>
    <child>text2</child>
   </parent>

child = <child>text3</child>
dup_child = <child>text3</child>
```

So what I want is after

```
parent.append_child_with_check(child)
```

xml should become

```
 <parent>
    <child>text1</child>
    <child>text2</child>
    <child>text3</child>
   </parent>
```

and after

```
parent.append_child_with_check(dup_child)
```

Xml should remain the same as I tried adding duplicate element.

```
     <parent>
        <child>text1</child>
        <child>text2</child>
        <child>text3</child>
       </parent>
```

Currently I am checking all the elements of a parent and if I found a match I break the loop and exit without adding but the performance degrades as the number of children increases.
As before every add all children as to be iterated to check for duplicates.
Not able to use set or dict here as the **hash** and **eq** are inherited from object and doesn't make sense in lxml elements.

Please suggest how to implement  `append_child_with_check(child)` with improved performance or If I am doing something wrong or missing an already existing library or method

The child can be an lxml tree in itself

Comment: Why don't you compute the set of elements (strings as the example shows) that need to be added in advance, and once the full list is known, start adding them under the parent *xml* node?

Comment: That's what I tried first. The problem is there are many different parents and the data I am receiving is tightly coupled and if I change one structure it impacts other's